# Proving an argument using resolution

Tags: logic

p --> q

q --> ~r V s

p

r

therefore:

s

I understand how to prove this by normal terms, but how would I go about solving this using resolution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite the premises as a set of [clauses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_(logic)#A_resolution_technique) :

> $\lnot p \lor q$
>
> $\lnot q \lor \lnot r \lor s$
>
> $p$
>
> $r$

and add the negation of the sought conclusion :

> $\lnot s$.

Then, apply the [resolution rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_(logic)#Resolution_rule) :

> the rule is applied to all possible pairs of clauses that contain complementary literals. After each application of the resolution rule, the resulting sentence is simplified by removing repeated literals. If the sentence contains complementary literals, it is discarded (as a tautology). If not, and if it is not yet present in the clause set, it is added to it, and is considered for further resolution inferences.

Thus, you can apply it to $\lnot s$ and $\lnot q \lor \lnot r \lor s$ producing : $\lnot q \lor \lnot r$.

Then apply the rule to this one with $r$ to get : $\lnot q$ and this in turn with : $\lnot p \lor q$ to get : $\lnot p$.

Finally, with : $\lnot p$ and $p$ we get the *empty clause* : $\Box$.

> If the empty clause is derived, the set of clauses is unsatisfiable (or contradictory), and hence it can be concluded that the soght conclusion follows from the premises.

Comment: Im having trouble following the resolution rule on wikipedia, would you be able to explain that?